# mongoDB (in nodeJS) aggregation pipleine returns empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm following Jonas Schmeddtman Node.js course and building a tour App. For some reason, when I send a request using postman on the route upon which this function is called, it returns an empty array instead of the manipulated data.

Below is my complete code. Thanks in advance.

```js
      exports.getTourStats=async(req,res)=>
      {
        try
        {
          const stats= await Tour.aggregate([
            {
              $match: { ratingsAverage: { $gte: 4.5 } }
            },
            {
              $group:
              {
                _id: { $toUpper: '$difficulty' },
                      numTours: { $sum: 1 },
                      numRatings: { $sum: '$ratingsQuantity' },
                      avgRating: { $avg: '$ratingsAverage' },
                      avgPrice: { $avg: '$price' },
                      minPrice: { $min: '$price' },
                      maxPrice: { $max: '$price' }
              }
             
            }
          ]);
          
          res.status(200).json(
            {
              status:"success",
              data:
              {
                stats
              }
            });
        }
        catch(error)
        {
          res.status(400).json(
            {
              status:"failed!",
              message:error
            })
        }
      }
```

//an example document is as below.

```
    "id": 8,
    "name": "The Northern Lights",
    "duration": 3,
    "maxGroupSize": 12,
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "ratingsAverage": 4.9,
    "ratingsQuantity": 33,
    "price": 1497,
    "summary": "Enjoy the Northern Lights in one of the best places in the world",
    "description": "dummy description",
    "imageCover": "tour-9-cover.jpg",
    "images": ["tour-9-1.jpg", "tour-9-2.jpg", "tour-9-3.jpg"],
    "startDates": ["2021-12-16,10:00", "2022-01-16,10:00", "2022-12-12,10:00"]
```

---

// schema.

```
const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A tour must have a name'],
    unique: true,
  },
  duration: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'a tour must have a duaration'],
  },
  maxGroupSize: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'a tour must have a max group size'],
  },
  difficulty: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'a tour must have a diffculty'],
  },
  ratingAverage: {
    type: Number,
    default: 4.5,
  },
  ratingQuantity: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'A tour must have a price'],
  },
  priceDiscount: {
    type: Number,
  },
  summary: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: [true, 'A tour must have a summary'],
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  imageCover: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'A tour must have an image cover'],
  },
  images: [String],
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now(),
    //to exclude the created at property from response sent back to user we put select property to false.
    select: false,
  },
  startDates: [Date],
});
//creating a model out of the schema we defined.
const Tour = mongoose.model('Tour', tourSchema);
module.exports = Tour;
```

Comment: Your query looks good, you need to check other possibilities, like verify collection name in schema and your original collection.

Comment: can you verify collection name in database, it would be `tours`, because when you don't give it will concat `s` after your model name.

Comment: yes its `tours` but i have the schema in a seperate file and then required like this `const Tour=require('./../models/tourModels');` 

so thas why im calling Tour.aggregate([//aggregation stages inside])

Comment: if you have data in `tours` collection then everything looks good.

Comment: yes , all other functions work fine. only this aggregation pipline function is not working properly.

Comment: hey, i figured it out :) 
i was performing $match on ratingsAverage while in the model, it was "ratingAverage" (without s) .

thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end of aggregation you should use [toArray()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#cursor.toArray).Then only aggregated values get instead of getting the aggregationCursor as out.

```
  exports.getTourStats=async(req,res)=>
  {
    try
    {
      const stats= await Tour.aggregate([
        {
          $match: { ratingsAverage: { $gte: 4.5 } }
        },
        {
          $group:
          {
            _id: { $toUpper: '$difficulty' },
                  numTours: { $sum: 1 },
                  numRatings: { $sum: '$ratingsQuantity' },
                  avgRating: { $avg: '$ratingsAverage' },
                  avgPrice: { $avg: '$price' },
                  minPrice: { $min: '$price' },
                  maxPrice: { $max: '$price' }
          }
         
        }
      ]).toArray()
      
      res.status(200).json(
        {
          status:"success",
          data:
          {
            stats
          }
        });
    }
    catch(error)
    {
      res.status(400).json(
        {
          status:"failed!",
          message:error
        })
    }
  }
```